# How to print "good morning/afternoon/evening" depending on the time of day?

Tags: php

The code below is meant to show my visitors something like "Good Morning, Today is ------ and the time is -----"

But I keep getting "Welcome" instead of the main greetings. Why is this?

```
<?php
$hour = date ("G");
$minute = date ("i");
$second = date ("s");
$msg = " Today is " . date ("l, M. d, Y.") . " And the time is " . date ("g:i a");

if ($hour = 00 && $hour <= 9 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59) 
{ $greet = "Good Morning,"; }

else {

if ($hour >= 10 && $hour <= 11 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59)
{ $greet = "Good Day,"; }

if ($hour >= 12 && $hour <= 15 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59)
{ $greet = "Good Afternoon,"; }

if ($hour >= 16 && $hour <= 23 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59)
{ $greet = "Good Evening,"; }

else { $greet = "Welcome,"; }
 }
echo $greet.$msg;
?>
```

Any idea on how to get this done?

How do I get timezones of my visitors automatically using php. My server's default timezone is Lagos/Africa. I want the code above to show my visitors their local time and date.

Comment: the first if statement, use `<=` instead of `=`

Comment: You are using  wrong equals operator  is == not =  if yiu use =  you are assigning the value to  the var ..

Comment: I already tried that @Cunning

Comment: What is the correct way? Correct my errors

Comment: This works perfectly https://3v4l.org/DqC3m I also apologize, use `>=`. check your semantics, syntax is ok.

Comment: btw, if it isn't `Good Morning,` nor `Good Evening,`, it will always be `Welcome,`. Then `$minute <= 59 && $second <= 59` are always true, no need to have them here.

Comment: Thanks @Federkun. Acknowledged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
 if ($hour = 00 && $hour <= 9 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59)
```

this way you assign 00 to $hour and all the other condition fails

you need

```
if ($hour == 0 && $hour <= 9 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59)
```

solved the if problem  there are others

You should keep in mind that php date() function return a string 
there are several way for solve your code problem these are just some suggestion
so you should commpare string (not number) or convert the string in number for commparision using a proper cast

Looking to your if you can also avoid the check for minute  ( are always  <= 59) this mean that you code  could be

```
  <?php 

      $hour = date("G"); 
      $minute = date("i"); 
      $second = date("s"); 
      $msg = " Today is " . date("l, M. d, Y.") . " And the time is " . date("g:i a"); 

      if ( (int)$hour == 0 && (int)$hour <= 9 ) { 
          $greet = "Good Morning,"; 
      } else if ( (int)$hour >= 10 && (int)$hour <= 11 ) { 
          $greet = "Good Day,"; 
      } else if ( (int)$hour >= 12 && (int)$hour <= 15 ) { 
          $greet = "Good Afternoon,"; 
      } else if ( (int)$hour >= 16 && (int)$hour <= 23 ) { 
          $greet = "Good Evening,"; 
      } else { 
          $greet = "Welcome,"; 
      }

      echo $greet.$msg;
  ?>
```

Comment: @VickyJane  this mean that the error related  to the wrong if sintax is solved  but you must define better  you logic .. for this i suggest  you of post a new proper question with well explain  you logic problem .. eventually with a proper data sample and the expectedc result  .. comment me the link when you have done

Comment: @VickyJane   . the code you are using for test is the same that you have posted in your question ?  ... please confirm..

Comment: Yes. But I changed this `if ($hour == 00 && $hour <= 9 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59){
        $greet = "Good Morning,";
        }`

Comment: well just more some info  ... how  do you set the $hour and $minute vars ?  .. if you can update you question adding some test case.. (some input value  that you are using,  the result you get and the expected  result) . i can evalute ..

Comment: Here's the complete code  `<?php
    $hour = date ("G");
    $minute = date ("i");
    $second = date ("s");
    $msg = " Today is " . date ("l, M. d, Y.") . " And the time is " . date ("g:i a");
    if ($hour == 00 && $hour <= 9 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59){
        $greet = "Good Morning,";
        }else if ($hour >= 10 && $hour <= 11 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59){
            $greet = "Good Day,";
            }else if ($hour >= 12 && $hour <= 15 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59){
 $greet = "Good Afternoon,"; }`

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
<?php
    $hour = date ("G");
    $minute = date ("i");
    $second = date ("s");
    $msg = " Today is " . date ("l, M. d, Y.") . " And the time is " . date ("g:i a");

    if ($hour == 00 && $hour <= 9 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59){
        $greet = "Good Morning,";
        }else if ($hour >= 10 && $hour <= 11 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59){
            $greet = "Good Day,";
            }else if ($hour >= 12 && $hour <= 15 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59){
                $greet = "Good Afternoon,";
            }else if ($hour >= 16 && $hour <= 23 && $minute <= 59 && $second <= 59){
                $greet = "Good Evening,";
            }else {
                $greet = "Welcome,";
            }

        }

    echo $greet.$msg;
?>
```

I recommend you read some tuts

Comment: Let me try. I'll give you feedback tomorrow if it works. Thanks anyway